# What is causing a 4 second long delay in "express:router use '/' query"?

Tags: performance, express

I am trying to learn more about authentication by going through Web Dev Simplified's "[Node.js Passport Login System Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RCnNyD0L-s)". I made it through the vid and started adding a few things, but I couldn't help but notice that there was a long (4 second) delay between when I start the server and when it is actually available for connections.

I started the express debugger and started lacing my code with console.logs and this is what I get:
[image: Output from express and server.js logs]

The code looks like this:

[image]

Dependencies are as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
```

I am suspicious of the addition of bcrypt and whether there is some "randomization" delay built into the library. I have looked at other express DEBUG dumps and others do not include this issue specifically with "express:router use '/' query" taking up so much time.

I know 4 seconds on the backend is not that big of a deal, but if I let this slide without attempting to resolve it (especially if it's a simply command line switch or env variable), then pretty soon my website will behave like all the other websites out there that force the users to wait 20 seconds until they're ready.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Your server only 'starts' once, so users shouldn't notice the 4s?

Comment: @Evert I know, this particular delay won't affect the end users, but, I'm asking this question to learn how to get a more granular output from server-side debug tools, if possible. Short answer, I don't know what's going on, and I can't seem to find any resources online that will help me debug. It just started happening about 2/3 through the tutorial. I'm hoping the answer is something about the 'way' I'm using the utilities (bcrypt, express, etc.). Two things I don't want to do are let this learning opportunity slide or start the web tutorial over from scratch.

Comment: 4s start-up time to load a bunch of libraries plus their dependencies doesn't sound that wild to me. Bcrypt is also a C extension, which I imagine might also take a bit longer. If you're really curious the best way to dig into this is to use a profiler. This might be a good starting point: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling

Comment: @Evert Thanks, that might be 'too' granular, but I am taking a look at it. It's not that 4s is too long, but it just started doing it and all of the other entries in the express debug messages are 0-3ms.